# Get registered users during the last 7 days

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to get registerd users during the last 7 days so I have the users table

```
+-----+------------+--------------+
| ID  | USERNAME   | ADDED        |
+-----+------------+--------------+
|  1  | Vlad       | 1347386878   |
+-----+------------+--------------+
|  2  | Test       | 1347386578   |
+-----+------------+--------------+
```

I tried below sql but the output is empty, no errors... and I need something descending from today to 7 days ago

```
SELECT date(added), COUNT(id) AS num_registered 
FROM users 
WHERE added < CURDATE() 
AND added > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAYS 
GROUP BY date(added) LIMIT 1, 7
```

Any suggestions how to do this?

**EDIT:**

```
$mysql_query = mysql_query('SELECT added, DATE(added), COUNT(id) AS num_reg FROM users_test WHERE added < (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - (7 * 24 * 60 * 60)) GROUP BY DATE(added) LIMIT 1, 7') or die(mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($mysql_query))
{
    $month = date('F', $row['added']);
    $day = date('j', $row['added']);
    $textbuilder .= '
    <li>
        <a href="#" title="'.$month.' '.$day.', '.$row['num_reg'].' registered">
            <span class="label">'.$day.'</span>
            <span class="count" style="height: 20%">('.$row['num_reg'].')</span>
        </a>
    </li>';
}
```

**TABLE:**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users_test` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
  `added` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO `users_test` (`id`, `username`, `added`) VALUES
(1, 'Test', 1347303641),
(2, 'Test1', 1347217241),
(3, 'Test2', 1347130841),
(4, 'Test3', 1347044441);
```

Comment: Check the format on the date that `CURDATE` is producing, and see if it's the same as `added`.

Comment: what is data type of ADDED column?

Comment: Try using GETDATE() or NOW() http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/06/21/sql-server-retrieve-current-date-time-in-sql-server-current_timestamp-getdate-fn-now/

Comment: @VladS since you put timestamp there, set it type right, so mySQL would know that it means. There are many built-in functions in mySQL to convert it when needed: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Comment: @WebnetMobile.com as I knew timestamp format is something like: 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ADDED` is a UNIX timestamp value, so just do this:

```
SELECT
    DATE(Added), Count()
FROM
    Users
WHERE
    Added > ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - ( 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 ) )
GROUP BY
    DATE(Added)
LIMIT
    1, 7
```

Note that this won't work in cases where you're dealing with leap seconds because it uses the approximate definition of a day as `24*60*60`, but I imagine you can live with that.

Comment: Remove the `LIMIT` clause and also try "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Added > ( UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - ( 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 ) )" and see what happens.

Comment: @Dai "SELECT added, COUNT(id) AS num_reg FROM users_test WHERE added > (UNIX_TIMESTAMP() - (7 * 24 * 60 * 60)) GROUP BY added" it's working without LIMIT clause.

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your timestamp into a `datetime` using `FROM_UNIXTIME()`. Since there are a large amount of conversions taking place, it would be easier to work with a derived table:

```
SELECT DATE(Added), COUNT(id) AS num_registered FROM
    (SELECT id, username, FROM_UNIXTIME(added) AS added FROM users) u
WHERE added < CURDATE()
    AND added > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 7 DAYS
GROUP BY DATE(added) LIMIT 1, 7
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIMESTAMP(added, ,  '%b %D, %Y'), COUNT(id) AS num_registered 
FROM users 
WHERE added > unix_timestamp() - ( 7 - 86400 )
GROUP BY FROM_UNIXTIMESTAMP(added, ,  '%b %D, %Y')
```